# Sitemap for dynamic PHP website ... the "lastmod" field is needed?

Tags: php, dynamic, xsd, sitemap

I've a really small website, so I usually update the sitemap by hand! 
In each "url" element there are the fields: loc, lastmod, changefreq and priority.

The "lastmod" field is setup to the date in witch I update the content of the related PHP page or the content that is loaded dynamically in the related PHP page!

I've tried to use http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to verify if all it was right, and I've noticed that in the generated sitemap there isn't the "lastmod" field!

In the Google wiki, about how to write a sitemap, there's written that is a good practice to setup the "lastmod" field even for dynamic pages; so, my question is ...

Is the "lastmod" field needed or not?

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard says that it's optionnal : http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#locdef :

> `<lastmod>` **optional**
>
> The date of last modification of the
>   file. This date should be in W3C
>   Datetime format. This format allows
>   you to omit the time portion, if
>   desired, and use YYYY-MM-DD.

Still, it might be usefull to let search engines / spiders know when your content was updated for the last time.

The [How do I compute lastmod date?](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.php#faq_computing_lastmod) entry of the FAQ also gives an interesting reason, that explains why you should include the lastmod date if you can *(quoting)* :

> Using even an approximate date or
>   timestamp can help crawlers avoid
>   crawling URLs that have not changed.
>   This will reduce the bandwidth and CPU
>   requirements for your web servers.

Comment: There are records Google/etc. ignores it (there is a quote somewhere by a Google engineer that the data is often useless because webmasters are forgetful), but there's no downside. I'd expect that updating that field with a page update would make Google re-index it much quicker than by Google's own initiative, but there's no guarantees anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

```
$lastmod = date('Y-m-dTH:i:s+00:00');
```

for more info,
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: the format string given above is incorrect. it should be `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s+00:00'`. also, to account for time zones, use this code instead: `$lastmod = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); $tzd = date('Z'); $lastmod .= ($tzd < 0)? "-".gmdate('H:i', -$tzd) : "+".gmdate('H:i', $tzd);`

Comment: echo date('c', $timestamp);

Answer (score 2):

You can use php date function to create last mod

How Last mode value is created
[image]

```
<sitemap>
    <loc><?php echo url('/') ?>/sitemap/uk/lse/list</loc>
    <lastmod><?php echo date('c', time()); ?></lastmod>
</sitemap>
```

Comment: your php code, for the last modified, is not working!

Comment: Hi Leo, It will provide the value like this "2019-02-06T06:11:27+00:00".Please let me  know any issues you have

Comment: Thanks, i have add `<lastmod><?php echo date('c', time()); ?></lastmod>` on my sitemap, but is not working is not showing the data and after I add that php code my sitemap shows some error

Comment: Please check manually you can add value <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>.This just says when the server is last modified.and it should be in following format https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

[It's not mandatory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps#Element_definitions) but it's good to have it in order to let Google (and other engines) know when content updates happen on your site.